# Error Rendering Controller: The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted

Tags: sitecore-forms

**Background -** We are upgrading from Sitecore 7.5 to 9.1.1 (CMS Only) with the existing code (Asp.Net Web Forms)

**Requirement -** We need to create new Sitecore Forms and wipe out the existing WFFM Module. Hence, we have wrapped the MVC Form rendering and inserted it on the existing web form without any change (using the below-given link). Form rendered on the web page successfully.

[Wrapping of MVC rendering over web form](https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/sitecore-mvc-aspx-interop/blob/master/SitecoreMvcAspxInterop/Pipelines/WrapMvcRendering.cs)

**Error Detail -**

**Issue -** Custom Action submission triggers the default FormBuilderController instead the custom class/code. Error details are given below,

```
Error Rendering Controller: Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Controllers.FormBuilderController, Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc. Action: Index: An unhandled exception occurred.

at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.ShowErrorMessage(ExceptionContext exceptionContext, ExceptionArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.Process(ExceptionArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Filters.PipelineBasedRequestFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.ExecuteController(Controller controller)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.Execute(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)

Inner Exception: The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines are running the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the configuration specifies explicit encryption and validation keys. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)
   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryWorker.Validate(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
```

Comment: multiple frontends? and no same machineKey  set?

Comment: @JanBluemink - I've already tried that way. However, still getting the same issue.                            
<machineKey validationKey="9CCD080A4FB97D46E0A08067DB848D5F75848D9CA3574C03B3FD895ADE14E79F589651AB1AE7117946211E4DC6D518C3D2553990B333FDFB4AFD9652CBCB88A6" 
        decryptionKey="F53E8FDF1D9264405DC7AFAD1B97FBE6E4E8B602F94C6677" 
        validation="SHA1"
        decryption="AES"
    />